# Only one checkbox selected

Tags: javascript, razor

I have a checkbox Yes and No so i want to user only able to use one. So if user tick Yes then No will cleared if Yes then no will clear

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="Check1" value="Value1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" style="margin:1em 1em 5px 5px" @(ViewBag.Status == "Yes" ? " checked" : "")/>Yes

    <input type="checkbox" id="Check2" value="Value1" onclick="selectOnlyThis(this.id)" style="margin:1em 1em 5px 5px" @(ViewBag.Status == "No" ? " checked" : "")/>No

<script>

     function selectOnlyThis(id) {
                for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
                    document.getElementById("Check" + i).checked = false;
                }
                document.getElementById(id).checked = true;
            }

</script>
```

Comment: The behavior you want is "radio", not "checkbox"

Comment: Why not use a radio button instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access elements that do not exist

your loop goes from 0 to 4 but your elements are `Check1` and `Check2`

So when it tries to set the `checked` property of `Check0` (*which does not exist*) it throws an error and stops execution..

Use

```
function selectOnlyThis(id) {
    console.log(id);
    for (var i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        var element = document.getElementById("Check" + i); // get element
        if (element){ // if element was found only the set its checked property
            document.getElementById("Check" + i).checked = false;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById(id).checked = true;
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/RHUVf/

---

or if your example html is the actual one you could just change your loop to

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, you are describing the behavior of a radio button. However, it is possible to make a checkbox behave like this also.

<kbd>[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fjj7Y/)</kbd>

```
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').not($(this)).prop('checked',false);
});
```

The above code does the following:

- `$('input:checkbox')` - selects all input elements of type checkbox
- `.not($(this))` - except this one
- `.prop('checked',false)` - unchecks the checkbox

This code uses the jQuery javascript library, so you must reference this library (usually in the head tags of the document), thus:

```
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks for not downvoting. I'll leave the answer just in case the OP elects to go this route (my own early js questions were best answered by jQuery, and now I prefer it).

Comment: yep.. jquery is pretty handy, but if you only need to set checkboxes it is overkill ;)

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot more helpful/easier to use HTML5 for this part 
IF you choose HTML5 the following code WILL work but if you decide not to use it It wont help.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="<name>" value="<value"><*explanation*><br/><br/> 
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```